# Why does node object value change?

Tags: python, queue, nodes

Below is my python code.

After setting `u.level` to `v.level + 1`, not only `u.level`, but also `v.level`, gets increased by 1. Also, when I do `u.level -= 1`, `v.level` is decreased by 1. Why does this situation happen? This situation also occurs in Java. What can I do to solve this problem?

```
import queue

class Node:
    level = 0
    height = 0 
    weight = 0


Q=queue.Queue()
u = Node();
v = Node();
Q.put(u)
v = Q.get() 
print("v_level : " , v.level)
u.level = v.level + 1
print("v_level : " , v.level)
print(u.level)
v.level -= 1
print(u.level)
Q.put(u)
v = Q.get()

#output
"""
v_level : 0
v_level : 1
1
0
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

For most of your code, you don't actually have two nodes. Instead, the names `u` and `v` are both bound to the same `Node` instance, which was originally `u`. The original `v` node was garbage collected after the name was rebound when you popped a reference to the `u` node off the queue:

```
Q.put(u)      # add a reference to u to the queue
v = Q.get()   # immediately take it off again, rebinding v to be the same as u
```

Honestly, I have no idea what you expected those lines to do. Their effect is identical to `v = u`, which I assume is not what you wanted.